# "$H_2/G_2$" and "$G_1/H_1$" meaning

Tags: group-theory, notation

I have the following problem:

> Let $f \colon G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ be an epimorphism, $H_2/G_2$ and $H_1=f^{-1}(H_2)$. Prove that $G_1/H_1 \cong G_2/H_2$. Is this still true if $f$ isn't surjective?

What does $H_2/G_2$ mean? I would assume it means "is a subgroup of" but I'm not sure. Also, which groups are supposed to be isomorphic? Again, I assume it's the quotient groups but I'm not sure. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like there's a typo.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Possibly, though it's used multiple times in the problem set. This is really weird notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to show an isomorphism of groups you do need that $H_2$ is normal in $G_2$. Hence I guess that $H_2/G_2$ means $H_2\trianglelefteq G_2$, i.e. $H_2$ is a normal subgroup of $G_2$. I have never seen this notation thou

Comment: Yeah, I assumed so too. Thanks for the quick answer.